# Making the background see-through, with a recticle staying visible

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor

I'm modelling a rifle, and am up to the scope. I now know how to use cycles with its nodes, but I don't get how to the scope crosshairs. The image is a crosshair on a white background. However when I put it into blender, even with the transparency, translucent, or glass BSDF nodes, the white background is still there.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of node setting:

[image]

The principle is the following:

- Your image is used as diffuse
- But it is also used as input to drive the mix shader
- This is driven by the white parts here: the more white the more the mix shader will use its second input which is here a glass

Using a glass shader can help to have this kind of zoom like effect, just changing the IOR value of the node:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely importing an image that doesn't have white set as transparent.

Is it a .jpg?  Those don't have an alpha-channel at all.

Open it in GIMP > Colors > Color to Alpha...
make sure that white is selected, click OK
File > Export as > filename.png > Export

[image]